# Netbeans menu is awful in Ubuntu - completely unreadable and bleh to look at. Any fixes?

Tags: linux, eclipse, netbeans, ubuntu

Hey. A lot of my colleagues use the Netbeans IDE for a few reasons and I would like to as well, however unlike them, I can't get over the look of the menus:

[image: Comparison of Eclipse and Netbeans]

Is there anything I can do to make the Netbeans menus look the same as the Eclipse menus?

Thanks.

Comment: If you're using the latest netbeans (7.0), you should post a bugrapport http://netbeans.org/community/issues.html. Because the netbeans gtk-skin visibly has a bug.

Comment: I'm using 6.9.1, installed from the Ubuntu repositories. I'll try 7.0 and report back.

Comment: Not installed from the repositories actually, but I am installing 7.0.

Comment: Still have the same issue with 7.0.

Comment: So, any clue on Ubtuntu GNOME desktops? Netbeans 6.9 and 7 works exactly the same for me, with bad menu fonts (for some items). I tried the netbeans font configuration and the Ubuntu preferences, but can't get the solution yet.

Comment: I ended up installing Openbox as my default WM. Not only is it faster and opens many windows instantaneously, it fixes the issues with Netbeans for me. Not a perfect solution, and perhaps not a solution at all for you, but there we go.

Comment: Same question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5819307/how-do-i-fix-the-deeply-broken-look-and-feel-issues-with-netbeans-7-0-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Netbeans is using your default window behavior (Window Decorations), not a built in theme. I'm using Kubuntu, so it may not be exactly the same, but the idea will be the same:

1) Right click along top of window and choose configure window behavior

2) Select Windows Deocrations

3) Choose from installed themes or download new ones. Kubuntu uses one called Oxygen by default, it looks pretty nice

Comment: Every other application has menus that look like Eclipse's, so Netbeans is the one using a theme.

Comment: The screen shot you are showing for netbeans is using Ubuntu specific colors and fonts. If I change the window decorations in the window that netbeans is running in, it changes it to whatever system theme I choose. In Kubuntu at least, you have the option to use different window decorators for specif applications.

Comment: It's using Ubuntu-specific colours, definitely, but not fonts or at least font-styling. You don't have the ability to do that in Gnome but even if you could it wouldn't solve the issue.

Comment: Windows DEOCRATIONS ++ ... funny Windows Deocrates :D

Answer (score 3):

I'm Using Ubuntu 11.10 and Netbeans 7.1.2 and had the same problem.

This is the solution which works for me:

1.) Edit

```
{Netbeans-install-dir}/etc/netbeans.conf
```

2.) Extend following line

```
netbeans_default_options="-J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m -J-XX:PermSize=32m -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -J-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true
```

with:

```
netbeans_default_options="-J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m -J-XX:PermSize=32m -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -J-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true --laf Metal -J-Dswing.aatext=true -J-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd"
```

You may replace "Metal" with "Nimbus".

Answer (score 1):

Workaround by avoiding the GTK-theme: I use the Metal or Nimbus LookAndFeel (LAF)

```
./netbeans --laf (Nimbus or Metal)
```

This makes it useable, at least.

---

Further issues:

- the LAF for `sudo ./netbeans` seems to be decent in contrast to plain `./netbeans` ([Discussion on NetBeans Mailing List](http://netbeans.org/projects/www/lists/nbusers/archive/2011-08/message/480), no solution named)
- I also encountered a very long loading time especially after the `Done loading modules...` screen, which might be related to the GTK-theme issue. This was accompanied by a `Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap"`. Fixing this warning also fixed the loading times. ([Discussion and fix on askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66356/gdk-gtk-warnings-and-errors-from-the-command-line))
- The aforementioned `Gtk-WARNING` is not thrown when executing netbeans via `sudo`

Comment: The menu did not work in full screen mode, using "--laf Metal" solves the issues (using Ubuntu 11.10 with Mate). Thank you